# Anatomy issue, stylized character

Tags: sculpting

I am sculpting this character(Luffy-One piece). I have lots of reference of the anatomy, sculpted a lot, but now I don't see what is wrong and what I need to improve. Can you see it and give me feedback? thank you.
[image]

This is the base reference, that I used to start.
[image]

Comment: the legs look very long, in reality they should be about as the same length as torso + head, but it may be a choice? Also maybe show a side view

Comment: Sorry, Now I am not able to show side view, but i added the reference, which i tried to copy. I guess, the length of legs of my character the same as the reference

Comment: yes it looks like the original has long legs